# Storing Files in S3, Referencing from Postgres

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, amazon-s3

When storing files in S3, what's the best way to reference those files from a Postgres database? The file's URL?

Comment: Since someone voted to close for being too broad, would you mind telling me what I should change to make this less broad?

Comment: I'm not the one who voted to close this question but according to the help center of stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you should ask specific programming questions. IMHO you should show what you have tried and what you are stuck on.